# PDO Mysql Update query appears to execute twice?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a script that runs an update query, yet it appears that the query is executing twice, as the value is incremented by double the number I give it each time (e.g. +2 adds 4 onto the value, +3 would add 6 onto the value). What am I doing wrong? Other questions of a similar nature here appear to have other flaws wrong with the code, but even if I keep it as simple as possible, it still appears to run the query twice. If I run it manually in MySQL, the query increments only once as expected.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
$query = $db->query("UPDATE basket SET quantity = (quantity + 1) WHERE user_id = 1 AND product_id = 4"); 
$query->execute();
die();
?>
```

Comment: You don't an `->execute()` anymore, `->query` already executes it

Comment: From what version was this change introduced?

Comment: you only need to call execute() if you're calling prepare() first, instead of query().

Comment: @JohnBergqvist what do you mean which version? this was already the default behavior, it executes query outright just like in other API's